What if You Are an Individual Contributor but Your Manager Asks You to Manage Whole Projects?
For context, I am working as a software/machine learning engineer, so the examples/terminologies may be domain specific, but likely, the general idea probably applies to non-tech teams as well.
So,I started at the company three months back, still getting familiar with processes and codebase. But, I am the youngest in the team, and lowest rung in the hierarchy as well, as in, no body reports to me.
So, the typical project requires contributions from frontend guys, infrastructure manager, some BI guy, some database admin etc, each of who have to do their parts for my manager to see whatever he thinks is the end result.
But, apparently, my manager is simply unaware of this simple fact or (because of some unknown reason), refuses to talk about it. He says I am the one responsible for my project, even going so far as telling he does not care who does what. He will never put in writing, or make it explicit who exactly is supposed to do what, and holding me responsible for project deliverables, not clearing up what is my deliverable.
I do not know whether I am not being tactful enough to convey the simple fact that, if a project X=X1+X2+X3, then only X1 is under my control, and the rest are under different people.
My manager keeps saying I have to learn to work with people, but it is kinda puzzling, as nobody complained that I am unpleasant to work with or talk to, or that I act like an asshole.
I try honest, professional, to the point communication, with an agreement like Bob will do X, Joe will do Y, Alice will do Z, so that in the end we have the deliverables ready to show a demo to the manager. But this conversation never happens.
Now to clarify things, here are some facts

My manager is not necessarily unpleasant in communication, he at least talks nice. But all I have is one-one with him, and he keeps insisting that I should meet the project deliverables. If I say Joe needs to do or should have done X for me to deliver the end-to-end project, then my manager acts like I am giving lame ass excuse. This is causing some friction, and I may have to face the axe
I am not claiming my peers (other individual contributors) are lazy, or not doing anything. They may have their own KPIs, and, to be honest, I do not know how their times are allocated on different projects. But if I request any of them do do something, they just cite their own work, or how busy they are. Obviously, all I can do is request, I am not their boss to tell them what to prioritise.
My complaint is not about the workload itself, I am not claiming I am being given unreasonable amount of work, but about the nature of the work. Am I supposed to deliver every project end to end?
When I show him a prototype based on my work (usually, something very technical and backend, not user or business facing, because of the nature of my work), my manager tells me it is useless by itself. That is true, like saying a backend SMTP server is useless unless there is a website (like gmail.com) for the users to to send emails.

I am not asking my peers to help me lessen my workload, I am asking (as an example) a database admin to create a new database necessary for a project, which is his job (if he takes the title seriously), I do not even have the technical privilege to do it, even if I have the expertise/knowledge. But he does not report to me, so he will avoid it for as long as possible, or straightaway refuse it.
Sorry for the rant, but I am genuinely curious how experienced professionals handle this. Some ideas that come to my mind are

Build a relationship with my peers, so that I can cajole them to do their job? I mean is that something every software engineer supposed to be able to do, because it seems like asking them to do their job is like asking them to do a personal favour to me.
Should I communicate something specific to my manager, using specific words and phrases that conveys who should do what, but does not sound like I am trying to skirt my work?
Am I approaching the whole thing wrongly? Should I just suck up and learn to do everyone's work? Some may say this is the way to grow in a role and they may be correct.
Has my manager just decided I am not worth keeping anyway (for some reason unknown to me), and this is just his way to make life difficult for me, prompting me to quit? There is no specific history or event that should suggest I am a bad/terrible employee, but I don't have all the information, it may even be part of a downsizing plan, who knows!

In any case, I want honest feedbacks from you guys, so that at least I can do better in my next job, assuming I will be out of this place soon.
I also know no boss wants to hear That is not my job, but, let's be honest, if that is true, then every employee is basically doing the CEO's job, basically end-to-end responsibility for everything, and every employee should get the CEO's compensation then?
In other words, if everything is everyone's job, why are there teams, then team leads, VPs, directors, C-suites?

From your description, it sounds like your boss wants you to take up a project manager role for this project, in addition to your technical work. Talk to your colleagues to find out how project management is usually handled in your company.

The management here is not good, not smart, not effective, and somewhat abusive.

What's your level of seniority?

@Helena mid-level, with experience in the industry, but not people manager. Does it mean if someone has a lower title than me, even if I am not in his reporting line, I have the authority to command his service? I thought the authority to command service goes strictly along the chain of command, hierarchically, not by corporate rank.

@Della yeah, strict authority goes along the chain of command. However, it's not uncommon for a team (e.g. programmers) to be assigned to work on a project and then that project's manager (or product owner) decides what exactly each week is to be worked on, without that person having a reporting line to the programmers. But that's what your company seems to be lacking: project management. Let me guess, it's a startup?

working as a software/machine learning engineer do you use something like Jira or something else to keep track of tasks? Or literally nothing except verbal communication with your boss?

Are those people (frontend engineer, BI engineer, etc.) completely external to you, or are they supposed to collaborate with you on the project as a team? Those are two very different situations, dealing with external org units (where a manager should be coordinating that, and you're certainly not responsible for this level of project management) and dealing with responsibilities within a team (where the team is expected to hash out responsibilities among themselves and only escalate if needed, and you are responsible for deliverables, and so is everyone else on the team).

@Della No, but more senior individual contributors are expected to be able to lead projects and get buy-in from without that degree of formal authority.

@Helena that's interesting. Maybe as a software engineer, I think too technically/literally, as in Bob will do X if his boss tells him to do it, but did not see convincing Bob to do it as my job. I can request, I can give technical specifications of what he needs to do, but if he says it's not his KPI to do it, or says it is something of least priority to him (because of other stuff on his plate), then I need a formal process to address it, instead of keep cajoling him, buy him a beer or somehow be extra friendly to him.

To some extent this is normal and it can feel overwhelming especially if you are new to the company/job.
You are indeed expected to build relationships with people in other departments, to co-ordinate with people that you have no formal authority over whatsoever and to do some amount of project management. The question here is whether the ask excessive or not.

holding me responsible for project deliverables, not clearing up what is my deliverable.


He will never put in writing,

These are indeed concerning and so I suggest leaning in harder into your boss.
If your manager is wishy-washy about the specific requirements and what you are on the hook for, you need to ask for clarification. Don't take "figure it out yourself" for an answer. That's acceptable for a "how" question but not for a "what" question. Push back. Ask about specific alternatives. "Do you want me to do option A or option B?" If they refuse writing anything down, write it down yourself and have them confirm.

Here is the specification that I am working to, can you please confirm that this is correct?"

If they ignore any written communication, you can add to it

"I will proceed under the assumption that's that what you want, unless I hear otherwise from you".

Keep copies.
Smaller projects are not that hard to manage, and it's a great skill to have. Take a spreadsheet, write down what you think the high level tasks and the dependencies are, put names/departments against them and eyeball the effort. Ask for help, if you need to:

Hey Bob, I need a data base with such & such features for my projects. Is this something you could do? If so, how much of your time would that take and when do you think you could do that? If not, who else should I be talking to? Thanks much !

If you get stalled by a resource then elevate to your boss using the word blocked: "The UI is going great but I am blocked for the data base".  If your boss tries to brush you of with "figure it out", reply with "I have tried A, B and C so far but I'm out of ideas. How do you suggest I proceed? What else could I do?"
Try this for a bit and see what happens. Keep notes, so you can document your approach and also assess what helped and what didn't. This approach may work, it may not, but these are all good things to do and practice and learn, so it's not wasted effort and time on your part.
If that doesn't improve the situation and if your manager keeps brushing you off you can either elevate inside the company (that's where note keeping is useful) or look elsewhere (or both).

When blocked, you don't even need to say what you've tried. Just say "I'm blocked on Mike creating the new database" or whatever. If your company uses project-tracking or bug-tracking software you can link the request you made to Mike, or you can cc your manager on the email you sent him. That said, a handy trick is to always ask for time estimates whenever you ask someone else to do something (and record it in writing). Then you can say "I'm blocked on Mike doing X, and he said he'll get it done by the 12th". That makes it clearer when escalation is needed.

I'll add that anytime you're blocked, report status to your manager frequently. Let them know as early as possible if someone else is delaying you, don't wait until after you miss a deadline. Also, it can help to explicitly ask them "can you help me escalate this?" so they don't assume you have it handled. Some managers are proactive about that sort of thing, but many aren't.

"To some extent this is normal" - Uhh... perhaps? I got my first job in 1986 and I've had... at least 16 different jobs across various industries since then and I've never been held responsible for someone else's work unless I was their supervisor. Another thing I think about related to this being "normal" is that some things that are bad and should never be done are still done very often by many people. So, I'm not sure if describing it as "normal" is fully accurate or helpful.

+1 for escalating but given what we've seen of this manager, be prepared for them to keep throwing it back at you. I wish I could tell you how to persist with this in honesty without the convo circling down to statement of the explicit need: "no Mr Boss, you chase them. Do your job."

If you are responsible, and noone else is officially required to support you, while the fulfilling of your responsibility requires the involvement of pother people, you are doomed to fail. And in the process of failure, you will quite likely ruin your body health and some of your mental health. (I know from my personal experience.)
So if you cannot convince your manager to organize things better and to support you, then you might need to find a better job, unfortunately.
NOTE: It is of less importance if your title is "carpenter" or "project manager" or "dude". The first question for you is as I mentioned earlier: can you succeed without ruining your health? If the answer is NO, then the other details are not of much relevance.

I agree with this post.  I think OP should seek another job, therefore.

This. Your manager is either incompetent or they are managing by abuse/fear (“if I abuse OP enough, they’ll do whatever it takes to get this done”). Good managers don’t operate this way. It’s true that you have some minimum level of initiative that you need to show to not just helplessly sit blocked all the time but a boss that makes you responsible for what you can’t control is not a good boss. If that’s the case here then leave ASAP.

I would say it depends on the company/team culture. If everyone has a specific specialization and each project is done as a team, Della should seek his/her colleagues' help. The first step for Della should be to talk to them, inquire about how this situation is handled usually (without criticizing the manager). In the end, every company is different. For example, we usually work on projects end-to-end and deliver to another team that builds upon it.

I have had the same. The manager is abrogating his job role onto you. From what I've seen of them, it is often too tempting and obvious to use one's position of power to "delegate" one's dirty work downward (difficult conversations, unpopular decisions). I wonder whether any eventual credit will flow the same...

@benxyzzy: The credit when the sh!t hits the fan, definitely yes. The credit when distributing bonuses, most likely not.

Go to the people responsible of X2 and X3, request their timeline, and make the project a success. If X2 or X3 does not play along, go to your manager and complain that they don't want to answer your request and you cannot work with them as they refuse to provide the things you need to work.
Looks like you become a project manager overnight. It can be a fulfilling job. If you seek something else, make it clear to your manager and demand a different job. When he refuses, look for another job.

What if their manager demands to talk to OP’s boss (“who is OP and why should I listen to them?!!”) and OP’s boss again dumps it in OP’s lap? This sounds like the actions of an abusive boss not a reasonable one.


I am asking (as an example) a database admin to create a new database necessary for a project, which is his job (if he takes the title seriously), I do not even have the technical privilege to do it, even if I have the expertise/knowledge. But he does not report to me, so he will avoid it for as long as possible, or straightaway refuse it.

I work as a sysadmin, and this is very surprising behavior on the part of the admin. To me, the only reason he would ever do this is because you aren't going through the proper channels (or he should be fired. this is inexcusable otherwise). Is there, for example, a ticketing system you should be going through for this type of support request? The wording in your question is not clear if you've actually asked the admin to do this already, or if you're just anticipating him blowing you off.
Generally, for a project, the project manager (whether that is your manager or yourself is not clear, see other answers) should allocate a portion of time for everyone needed to work on the project. if nobody is free, then that task cannot be completed, and it is up to the project manager to find a way to fix this (hire outside help, for example). This is separate from the general way admins should be supporting your work: admins generally do on-request work, most of the time using a ticketing system.

It's a little bit hard to discern where the problem is here, as the devil is always in the detail.
If you're being given a substantial amount of work to do for yourself, but it logically involves making a few requests of others, then your manager will expect you to handle those requests in the first place.
That includes justifying the request and its priority to the other person if necessary, following up at reasonable intervals if it can't be done straight away, and returning to your manager if the request is rejected in a way that permanently obstructs the work, or delayed in a way that doesn't seem reasonable to you.
This is a pretty reasonable approach to expect from even the most junior member of staff in any business I've worked in. If you're not doing at least this much, then this might be why your manager is saying it is no excuse to blame others for things not getting done. What your manager wants to see is that you're engaged in the monitoring of progress of a task which has been assigned to you by him, and that you're taking steps to progress it including communicating and/or resolving discovered obstacles.
Where it might be unreasonable however is if your manager is expecting you to apply unreasonable pressure to others by pestering at an excessive frequency, or to challenge resistance on the part of others which you have no obvious grounds to challenge and have no authority to investigate.
It might also be unreasonable if experience has already shown that another person of whom you are making a request, is very busy with important work and that they do not respond to requests from peers, or that any such request requires re-prioritisation at a higher level involving your manager, and your manager is resisting their own involvement under these circumstances.
When others are always very busy, it can also be obvious to technical staff, if not always to managers who may be non-technical, that arguing about requests and priorities is a form of work and a form of further undesirable demand and interruption upon a busy member of staff.
Do any of these other circumstances apply which mean you're having special problems making requests of others and getting requests fulfilled, or are you arguing with your manager about the very principle that you should often be expected to make and monitor direct requests of other staff in the course of your own work?

It is the later. In other words, if Bob (who is more senior than me and does not report to me) needs to do X, then convincing him (not just requesting) to do X (with carrot or stick, appropriate incentive) is becoming my job. And yes, Bob does not really respond to requests unless its part of his KPI or coming from his reporting line. But my manager is someone who is refusing to acknowledge Bob needs to do X, he says getting X done is my responsibility.

@Della, certain environments can concentrate multiple tricky or feckless characters together, so it's possible you may have to tackle things on two fronts here. Firstly, you might need to talk turkey with your own manager and insist that if he wants things done, then he needs to furnish the resources to get it done and participate in the marshalling of necessary corporate resources that you do not control, or else he needs to explain how the work can be done without the resources you currently seek. (1/2)

Secondly, you may need to investigate with Bob (or his manager) who is responsible for making decisions about the priorities of Bob's time, and who needs to be convened to consider requests involving Bob and make a binding decision about the acceptance and scheduling or not. You might need to ask what timeframes Bob has for making responses to direct requests, or how many rounds of argument are permitted before escalation, and ensure this is understood and agreed by your and his manager. (2/2)

There are a few issues conflated in this case. Based on what you've told us here:

Your manager reasonably expects you to interact with other people to get the dependencies you need in order to meet your deadline.

They would be reasonable to expect timely reports on blockers to meeting that deadline; for unmet dependencies this should include what you've attempted to unblock things.

It is destructive to the company for them to reject or discourage those reports. Note: It's unclear why you infer "then my manager acts like I am giving lame ass excuse." Specific facts would help here.

It is obviously unreasonable, once you've made a couple of those reports, for your manager to blame you for things you can't control. (Of course it happens all the time and probably at most companies.)


So take any plan like the following with a grain of salt, since none of us is there with you. Here's how I'd move forward.

DOCUMENT EVERYTHING. Any time you ask the DBA for "X" and they say they can't get to it today, confirm that in an email (backed up by Slack, Teams, whatever your org uses.) State your reasonable expectations for a timeline. You don't necessarily need to cc: your boss if you don't want to poke the bear. You must keep all this correspondence organized so you can find it.

Make a couple more attempts to inform your boss, either in writing or followed up in writing. If their response is oral, write it down contemporaneously, verbatim if possible.

If you still aren't making progress with either the dependencies or the boss, go to your skip manager / director, i.e. boss's boss. Summarize your attempts to meet the dependencies and your communications with the direct manager. Have your paper trail handy.


Full disclosure: This approach could end very badly, but only in situations where it was probably fated to end badly soon anyway. If your skip manager either doesn't care or backs up your manager reflexively, then your days there are going to be numbered.
But also consider -- in the process of writing down real evidence of your boss's behavior, you may find that it's less concrete than you implied here. Until they tell you specifically to stop reporting on unmeetable dependencies, keep doing it. Make them produce behavior that you can document.
